# Convert string to YAML map

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

In values.yaml I have another yaml config encoded to base64. In a template I decode it with

```
{{ $config := b64dec .Values.config }}
```

and I need to access it like a map, so what is needed is a kind of analogue of file AsConfig but for string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Helm's `fromYaml` function (haven't found any documentation besides [this commit](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/1686/files))

**config.yaml** which is encoded with `cat config.yaml | base64`

```
xxx: yyy
zzz: qqq
```

**values.yaml**

```
config: eHh4OiB5eXkKenp6OiBxcXEK
```

**secret.yaml**

```
{{ $config :=  (b64dec .Values.config) | fromYaml  }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret
type: Opaque
data:
  test: {{  $config.xxx }}
```

**helm template**

```
/mnt/c/home/chart> helm template .
---
# Source: chart/templates/secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret
type: Opaque
data:
  test: yyy
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. I've tried this before and I received a string that time, must have been my mistake. Anyway this is the best possible solution, thanks